# Node.js and Express on Windows

Tags: windows, node.js, express

Tonight I decided I'd try to build a simple Node.js application using Express on my Windows 7 machine.  The installation went fairly smoothly, but Express refuses to cooperate.  Here are the steps I've taken:

1. Installed Node.js using the MSI available at http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.6.9/node-v0.6.9.msi
2. Installed Express by running `npm install express g` from a command prompt.
3. Created a directory for the application `c:\source\node> mkdir newapp`.
4. Changed directory to the application directory `c:\source\node> cd newapp`.
5. Ran Express: `c:\source\node\newapp> express --sessions --css stylus`.

At this point the node.exe process fires up and runs endlessly at 25% CPU Time and continually uses more memory.  After running for 20+ minutes the node.exe process uses 300+ MB of Memory.  The `express` command never completes and the `newapp` directory remains unaltered.

If I run `express --help` I see the help output in the console.  I've tried running the command prompt as and Administrator but still Express appears to hang.

Does anyone have a clue what's going on or what I'm doing wrong?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a bug in the Windows version of Node v0.6.9. Filesystem access is pretty much messed up. Rollback to v0.6.8 http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.6.8/node-v0.6.8.msi and you should be fine.

The Express.js command line on Windows doesn't quite work well either. I just tried with Node v0.6.8.

This works

```
express --sessions myapp
```

This doesn't work for me

```
express --sessions --css stylus myapp
```

Fortunately you can add stylus support manually in your generated app. Open up `app.js` and in the `app.configure` function, add:

`app.use(require('stylus').middleware({src: __dirname + '/public'}));`

Hope this helps!

**Update:**

Oh ya, don't forget your NPM commands. In your app directory, you may need to `npm install jade` and `npm install stylus`.

Comment: Awesome!  Thanks for the response.  I'll have to try that out tonight when I'm back at my home dev machine.