# Node.js Modules Designed for Unix?

Tags: windows, node.js

I'm probably missing something, because I don't hear anyone else mentioning this.  But when I look at the process and file system modules I see a lot of Unix-isms that are unlikely to work on Windows.  How is this going to work for Windows users?  Windows users who never used Unix may not even realize which are Unix-isms, that are never going to work for them.  I suppose this is really just a documentation issue, it would be nice to filter documentation based on Unix or Windows.  Process.getuid() would be one example.  Chmod would be another.  Even SIGUSERn is there.  (Vague memories of servers mysteriously shutting down.)  I do have Unix experience from way back, but many will not have.  I avoided Rails because it was slow on Windows, but I hear that node.js is smoking fast on Windows, so I'm hopeful!

Comment: An example would definitely be great. As far as I know, a large portion of the Node API works fine on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Since version v0.6 (except the latest v0.6.9, big `fs` bug), Node.js has become a first class citizen on Windows. Because of this, it's my thought that most 3rd party modules will eventually support Windows. A lot of the major ones do now, [Express.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9091099/node-js-and-express-on-windows/9099426#9099426) most notably.

This will get better too. Some third party modules require the extra step of forcing the user to compile native C++ modules (NPM/node-waf automates this). However, in future versions Node.js will be ditching this for binary compatibility. The developers behind Node.js are trying very hard to emphasize a first class development experience that focuses on a pleasant developer experience across all platforms.

Admittedly, the Node.js experience will be better on OS X or Linux, but it's going to only get better on Windows. I highly encourage you to check it out if you haven't already.

Comment: Do you have a reference to the 0.6.9 bug? I've had issues with that version on Windows, but was looking for specifics.